# Spring The child context can share the parent context 'request

Tags: spring

I have created a child context from `applicationContext` at runtime, but it can't share the request (`HttpServletRequest`):

```
    this.integrationContext = new GenericApplicationContext();
    Resource xmlSource = new ByteArrayResource(integrationDefinition.getIntegrationXml().getBytes());
    XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(this.integrationContext);
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions(xmlSource);
    this.integrationContext.setParent(applicationContext);
    this.integrationContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("request", request);
    this.integrationContext.refresh();
```

I want to register it, but at this way, it losts the session. How can I register the whole request or get the session? Thanks.

Comment: Share what with whom? The parent can never see beans from the child, that only works the other way around.

Comment: the Controller layer can get the parameter-request,i want to share it with the child context.

Comment: Don't make the request a bean that will simply not work. It also looks complex what you are doing (which makes me wonder if you aren't doing things in a wrong way).

Comment: i was try to create a dynamic context that drive the spring-integration xml file.the child context need get the parent request parameter

Comment: my English level is no good,i dont know can you understand my words